# (Anti-)concentration of gap between largest and second largest component of multivariate random gaussian vector

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

Let $n$ be a large positive integer and let $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ be a zero-centered random $n$-dmensional real vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, an $n$-by-$n$ positive definite matrix with eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_n^2$. Let $Y_{(1)} \le Y_{(2)} \le \ldots \le Y_{(n)}$ be a rearrangement of the components of $Y$ in decreasing order, so that $\Delta := Y_{(n)} - Y_{(n-1)}$ is the gap between the largest and the second largest component of $Y$.

> **Question.** *What is a good approximation for the the asymptotic distribution of $\Delta$* ?

### Notes

- Any kind of hint on how to go about solving this problem will already be very useful to me; thanks in advance!
- I'm mostly interested in concentration and anti-concentration inequalities for $\Delta$, not the overall shape of its distribution.
- I'm fine with a result which only exploits spectral information about $\Sigma$ (its eigenvalues, etc.). Afterall, maybe this is all that can be done...

### Observation

The case $\Sigma = I_n$ has already in solved in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379688/78539), where it was shown that for large $n$, the distribution of $\Delta$ is approximatedly exponential with mean $1/\sqrt{2 \log n}$.

Comment: This would require a very big and very serious study. Even the apparently much easier question on the distribution of the maximum of an arbitrary Gaussian process, even on $[0,1]$, is a difficult problem of the Annals of Probability caliber -- cf. e.g. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176991419

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback.